# How should I call function with template recursively?

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

I'm trying to create a tree class in c++
and i'm not sure how should I use the templates when I am using recursion.

for example I have the following function:

```
template <typename Data>
void destroyTree(typename AVLTree<Data>::Node* element) {
    if(!element) {
        return;
    }
    destroyTree(element->getLeft());
    destroyTree(element->getRight());
    delete element;
}
```

or should it be:

```
template <typename Data>
void destroyTree(typename AVLTree<Data>::Node* element) {
    if(!element) {
        return;
    }
    destroyTree<Data>(element->getLeft());
    destroyTree<Data>(element->getRight());
    delete element;
}
```

then if I call it suppose from the following function:

```
template <typename Data>
void AVLTree<Data>::function() {
    destroyTree(root);
}
```

or:

```
template <typename Data>
void AVLTree<Data>::function() {
    destroyTree<Data>(root);
}
```

I've tried to combine most of the possibilities above but I always get an error.
usually it's a `non matching function for call to`

If someone has some experience with that issue please help me.

Thank you.

If I use Nawaz's suggestion I get the following error:

> Internal Builder is used for build ** g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c
>   -fmessage-length=0 -oAVLTest.o ..\AVLTest.cpp g++ -oAVLTree.exe AVLTest.o AVLTest.o: In function
>   ZN15Data_Structures7AVLTreeIiE4Node7getLeftEv':
>   C:/Users/Alex/workspace/AVLTree/Debug/../AVLTree.h:(.text$_ZN15Data_Structures11destroyTreeIiEEvPNS_7AVLTreeIT_E4NodeE[void
>   Data_Structures::destroyTree(Data_Structures::AVLTree::Node*)]+0x47):
>   undefined reference toData_Structures::AVLTree::Node::~Node()'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status Build error occurred, build is
>   stopped Time consumed: 532 ms.

what can I do with that?

all relevant code is [here](http://pastebin.com/p2j23Rqe).

Comment: They both work for me on GCC 4.7, what compiler are you using?

Comment: @szx: Both cannot work: the call which requires template argument deduction cannot work, because the template argument cannot be deduced.

Comment: @Nawaz: OK it seems I had to instantiate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct:

```
//in the first case
destroyTree<Data>(element->getLeft());
destroyTree<Data>(element->getRight());

//in the second case
destroyTree<Data>(root);
```

That is, you have to specify the template argument, as it cannot be deduced by the compiler from the function argument because it is a non-deducible context.

Comment: Thank you but what should I do with the error that I've mentioned below... I've got all relevant code here: http://pastebin.com/p2j23Rqe

Comment: @AlexFish: You should post the exact error (copy paste it here).

Comment: Internal Builder is used for build ** g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -oAVLTest.o ..\AVLTest.cpp g++ -oAVLTree.exe AVLTest.o AVLTest.o: In function ZN15Data_Structures7AVLTreeIiE4Node7getLeftEv': C:/Users/Alex/workspace/AVLTree/Debug/../AVLTree.h:(.text$_ZN15Data_Structures11destroyTreeIiEEvPNS_7AVLTreeIT_E4NodeE[void Data_Structures::destroyTree<int>(Data_Structures::AVLTree<int>::Node*)]+0x47): undefined reference toData_Structures::AVLTree::Node::~Node()' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status Build error occurred, build is stopped Time consumed: 532 ms.

Comment: @AlexFish: Why dont you post this error in the question itself?

Comment: I probably should but I get this error only if I have my code in the way that you have suggested in your answer. In any other case I have a different error.

Comment: @AlexFish You have to define `Node`'s destructor or remove the declaration if you don't need it

Comment: Great! I didn't think it would be a problem. It solved my problem. Thank Nawaz!